# Select items from one specific year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have a table with a field Order_Date in datetime format.
And I'm writing a query thats selects me only all the products for this year.
But I have really no idea how I can write that.

In "pseudo-query" it should be something like that :

```
SELECT * FROM produit WHERE Order_Date(year) == now(year) order by Order_Date desc
```

Comment: ">= jan-01- this year" and "<= dec-31 this year"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it backwards. When you want to call a function on a column, you put the function name outside the column name. So it's

```
WHERE YEAR(Order_Date) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Comment: Oh I was almost there... Thanks, it works exactly like I wanted ^^

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM produit WHERE YEAR(Order_Date) = YEAR(NOW()) order by Order_Date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your query in a sargable way as

```
SELECT *
 FROM produit
 WHERE 
Order_Date between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01') 
and DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-12-31')
order by Order_Date desc
```

or

```
SELECT *
 FROM produit
 WHERE 
Order_Date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01') 
and  Order_Date <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-12-31')
order by Order_Date desc
```

So if you have an index on your `Order_Date` then query will use index but if you apply any function on your column query will not use an index for see [**Sargable**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)